# Independent t-test: non-significant different!

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I ran ind. t-test and find that no significant different for the two means. So, does this meant discouraging? Mean for A is higher than B, so i did planned to conclude that A is actually favoring compared to B. However, in my current state with no significant different btw the two means, what can i conclude from the different mean score since that were not statistically different? please helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the P.value of the difference between your means? This will be the number of times out of a 100 that you will expect to see that difference just by chance. So if you have a P.value of 0.13, it means that you can expect to see the difference in means by chance 13% of the times you do the experiment.

If a P.value of 0.05 is your cutoff, you should report the difference in means and say something like "The differences in means however were not statistically significant at a significance level of 95% / 0.95).

Generally though, I'd advise you to check if the distributions are normal using the Shapiro-Wilks test or the Lilliefors test before you use a t.test - the validity of t.tests is dependent on the data being normally distributed.